# Who i can add video from URL to my application in Codename One

Tags: java, android, url, apk, codenameone

i need code to play video from multi video URL like movies or else
i use Code name One to develop programmers.
i use this code for play video in the application or phone stadio
who i can edit this code to play video from URL:

```
private  MediaPlayer mp;
public  void setVideoURL(Container con, String videoUrl, Runnable onCompletion) {
    scheduleBackgroundTask(() -> {
        try {
            Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(videoUrl, true, onCompletion);
            video.prepare();
            callSerially(() -> {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.getMedia().cleanup();
                }
                mp = new MediaPlayer(video);
                mp.setAutoplay(true);
                video.setNativePlayerMode(true);
                con.removeAll();
                con.add(CENTER, mp);
                con.revalidate();
            });
        } catch (IOException err) {
            Log.e(err);
            ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Error loading video: " + err);
        }
    });
```

Thank.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output / tracebacks). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The code you included in the question literally plays a video from a URL. In this example con is the parent container which could be a Form etc.

Comment: but when i put code its cant run

Comment: @Yazan What's the error?